# CSS/HTML elements overlap and move on browser resize

Tags: html, css, browser, resize

So I have a website that I would like to be responsive as the elements do not move when the browser is resized.
In fact I would like it just like the StackOverflow website itself. I have heard many people having this problem but none of their solutions seem to help. Also if you see an error in any of the code please say so.

CSS is as follows:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
body {
    background: #ccc
}
#container {
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    left: 25%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
}
/* Navigation menu start */
#Nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
}
#Nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    background-color: #A1A1A1;
    height: 400px;
}
#Nav ul li a {
    padding: .4em 10em;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid blue;
}
#Nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #A1A1A1;
    background-color: #616161;
    width: 100px;
}
/* Navigation Menu End */

/* Left side content area */
#left {
    width: 8.7%;
    margin-left: 1px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    border: solid black;
}
```

Comment: ^^ Agreed. And StackOverflow is not considered a responsive site :-P

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'responsive', but this site isn't responsive, if my tired eyes are right? :)